# adding border bottom color on react styled element

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, react-context

I'm working on a basic calculator app with dynamic themes to be applied. How do I add a dynamic style react border-bottom with a set color on the `keyStyle` constant to be applied on my buttons?

I can't pass the value of `currentTheme.numKeyShadow` in the `borderBottom` css style as it's already a string.

How do i go about this?

This is a snippet my code:

```
import { useStateContext } from '../context/contextProvider'

const NumKeys = () => {
  const { currentTheme, SetCurrentTheme } = useStateContext()

  const keysStyle = {
    borderRadius: "8px",
    borderBottom:"4px solid",
    borderBottomColor: currentTheme.numkeyShadow,
    backgroundColor: currentTheme.keysBackground
  }

  return (
    <section>
     <div className='numKeys'>
          <button style={keysStyle}>1</button>

     </div>

    </section>
  )
}

export default NumKeys
```

This is my part of my data source:

```
export default [
     {
          "id": 0,
          "background": "#3a4764",
          "keysBackground": "#232c43",
          "screenBackground": "#182034",
          "KeysBackground": "#637097",
          "KeysShadow": "#404e72",
          "equaKeyBackground": "#d03f2f",
          "equalKeyShadow": "#93261a",
          "numKeyBackground": "#eae3dc",
          "numKeyShadow": "#b4a597",
          "num": "444b5a",
          "equal": "#ffff"
     }
]
```

Comment: It's more than likely a problem with your implementation of the Context Provider than your CSS, because the CSS is valid (Setting the border bottom color separately from the width and style.) -- though not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a context or custom hook here. The CSS for the theme is a constant, and hence, you can declare, import and export like a simple JavaScript file.

NumKeys.js (React component)

```
import theme from "./Theme";

const NumKeys = () => {
  const keysStyle = {
    borderRadius: "8px",
    borderBottom: "4px solid",
    borderBottomColor: theme.numKeyShadow,
    backgroundColor: theme.keysBackground,
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="numKeys">
        <button style={keysStyle}>1</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default NumKeys;
```

Theme.js

```
const theme = {
  id: 0,
  background: "#3a4764",
  keysBackground: "#232c43",
  screenBackground: "#182034",
  KeysBackground: "#637097",
  KeysShadow: "#404e72",
  equaKeyBackground: "#d03f2f",
  equalKeyShadow: "#93261a",
  numKeyBackground: "#eae3dc",
  numKeyShadow: "#b4a597",
  num: "444b5a",
  equal: "#ffff",
};

export default theme;
```

This would add the style in your React component.
Live version - https://codesandbox.io/s/theme-0t9773

Comment: Thank you for your answer@Rahukg007, but the thing is I only dropped a part of my data source(themes array). There's still about three other objects with different color values in it so I can toggle between different themes. Now my question is, how do I assign the theme Array to a state so I can loop through the id on click of a button. I'm not sure if I did a good job explaining but do I need to drop the rest of my code??